# Decomposing a composite function: $f(g(x))=\frac{x^4+x^2}{1+x^2}$, then $f$=?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We have a composite function $f(g(x))=((x^4+x^2)/(1+x^2))$ and a single function $g(x)=1-x^2$. We want to know $f(1/2)$. From theory we know that $g(x)$ had been plugged in $f(x)$, but how would i find standalone $f(x)$ from here? I thought of dividing the result by $g(x)$, but that isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate way to do this is to find an $x$ such that $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Since $$g(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = \frac{1}{2}$$

We have $$f(\frac{1}{2})=f(g(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}))=\frac{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^4+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{1+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

You may write
$$
f(g(x))=\frac{x^4+x^2}{1+x^2}=\frac{x^2(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}=x^2=1-(1-x^2)=1-g(x)
$$ Thus
$$
f(x)=1-x.
$$ Then

> $$f(1/2)=1/2.$$

Comment: small typo - should be $f(x)=1-x$.

Comment: @GyuminRoh Thank you!

Comment: This is correct, but it's not a general approach to decomposition of functions right? It wouldn't be possible to perform the same operations on other functions, right?

Comment: @Συλχαν You are right! But a general approach does not really exist... Thanks.

Comment: As shown in @GyuminRoh answer decomposition is not required and as mentioned above generally decomposition won't be easy.

Comment: Why does $1-g(x)$ result in $f(x)=1-x)$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, (at least if we only consider functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$),  $f$ might also be given by $f(x)=\begin{cases}1-x&\text{if }x\le 1\\42&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Itis only because $\frac12$ is in the image of $g$ that this works